# How to make same to "slide to unlock" button?

Tags: android

The task is to move object (image, for example) in special path, for example circle. Just pressing on image and sliding over the path for getting some result. Maybe its drag'n'drop, but user will be able slide object hole the screen, not only in my circle-path. Simply it classic slide-to-unlock, but trajectory is not line, but any other figure.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I have to admit that your English is a bit of a barrier. My understanding of this question is, you have a circle on screen with an object in the middle. You want to be able to detect when somebody drags the object outside of the circle? Is this correct?

Comment: No. We have any figure on the screen, example circle. On this thircle we have object. Not in middle, just on the line, on circle. And i want to drag my object only on circle. We cant to drag object behind the line of circle. We have one way to drag - only on line.

Comment: If we have vertical line - we can drag object only up and down. Horizontal line - only left and right. When you unlocking your phone that magic button can move only left-right, not up or anywhere else from line-path.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what he wants to do is to replicate the unlocking mechanism, where you have a said shape (round in the case of the Android slide to unlock in 2.3.3) and you can only move it according to a certain ... "track". 

So I think he wants to create a "track" that an object could "clip" to in order to have a defined path that it could move, some kind of boundaries, guiding the user motion input.

Comment: @m9_psy Ok, Sorry for the misunderstanding. That was my second guess. I understand what you want done now.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeRoy, yes. I think we just need to repeat simple "slide-to-unlock". Then ill try to make more complex thing.